# Is it bad programming practice to name a method the same as the return type for that method?

Tags: oop, methods, types

**Setup:** Example

```cpp
typedef struct{
    float x;
    floay y;
    floay z;
} Cartesian;
typedef struct{
    float alph;
    floay beta;
    floay r;
} Polar;
class MyObject{
public:
    Polar m_position;
public:
    Cartesian Cartesian();//getter
    Cartesian Cartesian(Cartesian set_val);//setter
}
```

Here the position is stored in polar form. 
A method is provided to retrieve the Cartesian form, and is named to make sense in such a call as `obj.Cartesian();`
The setter method has the same because I personally don't see the point in get set prefixes when Overloading is possible.

**Is it bad programming practice to name a method the same as the return type for that method?**

Comment: You should call them getCartesian() and setCartesian(...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly idiosyncratic and that in itself will make your code difficult to read.

A convention that's reasonably established is to use `CamelCase` for class names, and `camelCase` for function names.

So you could write

`Cartesian cartesian(); // getter`

for example

Note that a function with the same name (and case) as the class is often reserved for a *constructor*.